# Firefox only works with every other video.js

Tags: video.js

I'm using video.js with mp4 files, it works fine in chrome, but only runs properly on every other video (even ones, not odd ones)

My code is formatted like this

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
<video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls data-setup="{}" width="580" height="317">
<source src="/path/to/file.mov" type="video/mp4">
Video tag not supported.
</video>
```

Making the video an absolute link does not work, self closing or normal closing of the source tag does not work, removing "Video tag not supported." does not work. The only work around I have right now is to load an empty video tag before each actual video and then hide it with css.

The videos that fail to load have a div with the same attributes as my video tag, a fluid-width-video-rapper div inside that, and a swf object, but none of the vjs divs